# Median-computation ("grouped median"). Problem with gmedian-computation in SPSS

Tags: computational-statistics, median, software

In my basic-statistics course I wanted to delve deeper into the problem of the (grouped) median-computation and did some computations using SPSS. The protocol seems to indicate either a different ansatz which I did not yet anticipate correctly or a an error in the implementation. After two days of fiddling with tests and recomputations it seems to me that it is an error.
To make things simple, I generate a test data set with $3$ categories of data: class "`1-1.999..`","`2-2.999..`","`3-3.999..`", where SPSS works expecting the class means, so I provide the data for SPSS with the class-mean-values computed as  "`1.5`","`2.5`","`3.5`".
I call the procedure as

> frequencies testvar /statistics median /grouped testvar.

where I provide the data just as a column in a simple dataset.

The general frequencies table is 
$$ \begin{array} {r|r} 
  \text{value} & \text{freq} \\ \hline
   1.5 & 4 \\
   2.5 & 5 \\
   3.5 & x \\
\end{array} $$
where I let variate $x$ from $2$ to $10$ giving $N$ from $11$ to $19$. The median should lay in the second class/category for $N \lt 18$.
This is the table of medians, depending on $N$:
$$ \small \begin{array} {r|rrr| |r|rrr|r} 
   \text{cat:}&1.5 & 2.5 & 3.5 & N && \text{gmedian (SPSS)}&& \text{expected}^{a)} \\ \hline
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 2 & 11 & & 2.27777... &= 2+ {5 \over 18}  & 2.3 \\
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 3 & 12 & & 2.38888... &= 2+ {7 \over 18}  & 2.4 \\
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 4 & 13 & & 2.5        &= 2+ {9 \over 18}  & 2.5 \\ \hline
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 5 & 14 & & 2.6        &= 2+ {12 \over 20} & 2.6 \\
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 6 & 15 & & 2.68181... &= 2+ {15 \over 22} & 2.7 \\
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 7 & 16 & & 2.75       &= 2+ {18 \over 24} & 2.8 \\
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 8 & 17 & & 2.807...   &= 2+ {21 \over 26} & 2.9 \\
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 9 & 18 & & 2.857...   &= 2+ {24 \over 28} & 3.0 \\ \hline
   \text{frq.:}&4 & 5 & 10 & 19 & & 2.9       &= 2+ {27 \over 30} & 3.0 \\
\end{array}  \\ 
\small{ \_^{a)} \text{Median}_\text{expected}=2+{N/2-4 \over 5}\cdot (3-2)} $$
What we observe is not only the difference in the values of the medians (which might be correctable by a tiny tweak).
But even more important/surprising is the observation of the ***linear*** increase of the median for $N=11$ to $N=13$ *(which we in fact expect)*, but once the index for the median-case moves from the left(=lower) part of the median category over its mean-point to the right(=higher) part, then the linear increase changes to a ***nonlinear*** one (the denominator changes with N). But the denominator in the official median-formula does not change as long as the index points to the same category: it should just contain the number of cases, possibly additionally divided by the fraction of the values of the categories. So even if I have a tiny misconception here, which might then explain the linear difference for the smaller $N$'s, I think there must be some error in the SPSS-internal routine.

> Question: So what is going on here? Or did I overlook something important/simple?

---

Remark 1: This consideration was also inspired by the tech-article in the [IBM-SPSS knowledgebase concerning the gmedian-computation and the use of the category-means](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21475408)
Remark 2: The formula in the SPSS-algorithms-manual is not completely clear to me, but it does not seem so far to give reason for the observation of the varying denominator.
Remark 3: From the IBM_SPSS-algorithms-manual, "grouped median" [image: picture]